# Comparing variable to array values in $(window).scroll Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

So, like the title said, I'm having trouble trying to figure out a way to compare a variable, `currentOffset` to my array `offsets`. So, let's say I have currentOffset inside a `$(window).scroll();` event, like so...

```js
var currentOffset = 0;
var sections = $('section').get();
var offsets = [];

var i = 0;
sections.forEach(function () {
    offsets.push($(sections[i]).offset().top);
    i++;
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    currentOffset = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

How would I ***constantly*** check whether or not the `currentOffset` is >= one of the offsets in my array. So lets say the the array contains the following data...

```
[8, 332, 656]
```

When the user scrolls, and the `currentOffset` either is `8` or is greater than `8`, then trigger an event. Then when the user hits `332`, or scrolls to a greater depth than `332` then trigger another event.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is .get() what you want to use? It seems that maybe toArray() might what you're after.

Comment: @Donutttt They both return an array. .toArray() is probably the correct way to return the section values. However .get() seems to return the same. Unfortunately that doesn't really solve my question.

Comment: cool, thanks, that's good to know. Are you trying to get the css attribute 'top'?

Comment: @Donutttt No, I'm trying to figure out how to procedurally compare the currentOffset to each key in the array.

Comment: Is this on the right lines? https://jsfiddle.net/LsLaeakj/

Comment: And an updated version to make it clearer... https://jsfiddle.net/LsLaeakj/1/

Comment: @Donutttt That's perfect, please put it in an answer so I can mark it as correct! :)

Comment: Done - thanks for helping me to the conclusion ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle:

jsfiddle.net/LsLaeakj/1

```
var currentOffset = 0;
var sections = $('section').toArray();
var offsets = [];

for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
 offsets.push($(sections[i]).offset().top);   
}

console.log(offsets);

$(window).scroll(function () {
    currentOffset = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(checkOffset());
   $('section').css('background-color', 'white'); $(sections[checkOffset()]).css('background-color', 'red');
});

function checkOffset(){
 for (var i = 0; i < offsets.length; i++){
    if (offsets[i] > currentOffset){
        return i-1;
    }
 }
 return offsets.length
}
```

It sets the last offset div to have a red background, and logs it to the console. Obviously this can be changed but hopefully it illustrates the functionality you were after.

Answer (score 1):

try to rewrite the loop like this:

```
var offsets = [];

$.each($('section'),function (i,v) {
    offsets.push($(v).offset().top)
});
```

then inside the scroll event use this:

```
var prevScroll = offsets[0]!=null ? offsets[0] : 0;
var toTrigger = 0;
$.each(offsets,function(i,v){
    if(i>0 && currentOffset >= prevScroll && currentOffset < v){
        toTrigger = i;
        return true;
    }
    prevScroll = v; 
});

switch(toTrigger){
    case 1: 
        function1();
        break;
    case 2:
        function2();
        break;
    case 3:
        function3();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the scroll callback you could just loop through each array value and test. Breaking if you find one. This assumes the array is in increasing order as well.

```
var offset, nextOffset, length = offsets.length;
for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
    offset = offsets[index];
    nextOffset = offsets[index + 1];
    if (index == length - 1 && currentOffset >= offset) {
        // if last index don't bother checking next value, trigger event
    }
    else if (currentOffset >= offset && nextOffset && currentOffset < nextOffset) {
        // trigger event
        break;
    }
}
```